# Two array merge or push for JSON

Tags: php, arrays

I have two PHP array like below,

```
$health_table1[]    = array(
            'department_name'   =>  $department['department_name'],
            'department_total'  =>  $department_total);


$health_table2[]    = array(
            'status_name'   =>  $status['status_name'],
            'status_total' => $status_total);
```

I want to merge this two array in such a way, that it should output JSON as below,

```
0   
:
{department_name: "Iphone", department_total: 1, status_name: 'test1', status_total: 5}
1
:
{department_name: "Macbook", department_total: 2, status_name: 'test2', status_total: 7}
2
:
{department_name: "Training", department_total: 0, status_name: 'test3', status_total: 9}
```

I tried with array_merge, array_push but did not help,

Any help appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume arrays have the same length.

I don't know how you try, but you can do with `array_merge` like this

```
$return = [];
foreach($health_table1 as $key => $value){
   $return[] = array_merge($health_table1[$key], $health_table2[$key]);
}

echo json_encode($return);//<- here is the merged array.
```

Comment: @Dainel, Yes it worked, added other array's key values in first array, but what if 2nd array have different length?

Comment: @rjcode It depends what you want to do. if you want to have values from only one array if one is shorter or to have only the values where both array have values. You will have to adapt with some ifs to check what array if longer.